# Why does table need to exist to run php artisan commands Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am wondering why I can't run `php artisan` commands on my recently cloned laravel project. I get an error `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:`. I don't get why this is occurring, as I'm trying to run `php artisan migrate` after having created the database on this machine. Of course the base table or view is not found... Why would this happen and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Is there anything more to that error message, such as the table name it can't find? Or is it empty as you've quoted?

Comment: Yes it also gives a table name. In full the error is `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myapp.thistable' doesn't exist`

Comment: Perhaps your code is using the model associated with that table somewhere, under the assumption that data (or at least the table) exists. This could be in a service provider or really anywhere in your code. Laravel will bootstrap service providers and such on Artisan calls. It's hard to say specifically without your code.

Comment: Can you post a dir listing of db migrations?

Comment: did you check if you are connected to database?

Comment: @MathewMagante I think this may be part of the problem. Every time I get into mysql via terminal, even after I `USE database` it resets itself up exiting.

Comment: I think you need to fix your database connection first (.env file)  before to use artisan. Try to follow this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database

Comment: Why would the database not stay in use? My .env file is set up correctly, as this was simply cloned from github repo, and this project works on my other machine. But I created the database in mysql, and use it, but after I exit and recheck, the database is null

Comment: Do you have any custom console commands?  I had this problem  because I was accessing a user in the constructor of a custom command.  It seems to initialize all the commands when you run any of them.

Comment: Just one, but it is not dependent on any models. It was simply a test I made for task scheduling.

Comment: The issue stemmed from `jobs` I have created that were reliant upon model data